# React Testing getByText not working for p element

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

This is my Test :

```
describe('Address Section', () => {

const address:Address = {
    addressLine1: '23 Max Lane',
    addressLine2: '#2',
    city:'Hoboken',
    state:'NJ',
    zipcode:'07086'
}

const {getByText, container} = render(<AddressSection 
{...address}/>);

  ---------> THIS TEST WORKS
 it('finds address label', () => {
    const addressDiv = getByText('Address');
    expect(addressDiv.className).toBe('address-label');
 })
   ---------> THIS TEST DOES NOT  WORK 
it('finds addressline 1', () => {
   const pNode = getByText('23 Max Lane');
   expect(pNode).toBeDefined();
})
```

This is my component:

```
  function AddressSection(props:Address) {
   return (
     <div>
        <div className="address-label">Address</div>
        <div className="address-value">
          <p>{props.addressLine1}</p>
          <p>{props.addressLine2}</p>
          <p>{props.city + ' ' + props.state + ' ' + 
               props.zipcode}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

I get this error. Unable to find an element with the text: 23 Max Lane. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Comment: Does it work if you move the `render` part inside the `it` block?

Comment: @GiorgioPolvara-Gpx thanks. I realized I was doing a cleanup which I thought was happening after ALL tests, but accidentally was happening after each test.

Comment: It is supposed to run after each test. Do run `render` inside every `it` statement. RTL's newest version runs `cleanup` for you and it does it after each test. Tests with a "global" `render` will break